# replace radio button with css button and keep label in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4QZED/2/. (Explosion Pills updated version - http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/4QZED/4/ )Instead of showing the normal radio, or replacing the radio with an image. i would like to replace it with a div i can dress up as a button and on hover the class changes and on click the class changes. but also on click the hidden radio is selected. but also require the label (label in reference to the text showing e.g as below .co.uk .com .net etc.) to be inside the div/button. or be able to add text to the div button. is this possible?

```
$(function() {
    $("input [name='domain_ext']").each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).after($("<div class='radioButtonOff'> label </div>"));
        } else { 
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).after($("<div class='radioButtonOff'> label </div>"));
        }
    });

    $("input.radio").click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('src') == 'radiobuttonOn') {
            $(this).attr('src', 'radiobuttonOff');
            $(this).prev().attr('checked', 'false');
        } else { 
            $(this).attr('src', 'radioButtonOn');
            $(this).prev().attr('checked', 'true');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Both of your selectors are wrong.

Comment: don't leave a space between input and [name=domain_ext] and use input[type=radio] if you want to select radio inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've attempted to improve upon your solution to get it to work the way you want.  You had several errors.  Most importantly, there is a vastly important difference between `input[name=domain_ext]` and `input [name=domain_ext]` (the space is the descendant selector).  You were also using `$(this)` in the checked event to apparently change the divs, but the event was bound to the inputs.  There's also a difference between `input.radio` and `input[type=radio]`.

```
$("input[name='domain_ext']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).after("<div class='radioButtonOff'> label </div>");
    } else { 
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).after("<div class='radioButtonOff'> label </div>");
    }
});

$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.radioButtonOff').add('.radioButtonOn').toggleClass('radioButtonOff radioButtonOn');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/4QZED/4/

Comment: thank you, big improvement.. do you think the best way is to use span and class to place the radio label e.g .co.uk into the div button?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean

Comment: where the css button contains the word label. i need the radio button label to replace that text "label", which currently is in the div/css button